# Show that if $\lambda A + \mu B$ is nilpotent therefore $tr(A^kB)=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A,B \in \Bbb M_n(\Bbb C)$. Show that if $\forall \lambda, \mu \in \Bbb C, \lambda A + \mu B$ is nilpotent therefore $\forall k \ge 0, tr(A^kB)=0$.

I looked at some particular cases ($k=0$ ; $B=I_n$ ; $k=1$ ; when $AB=BA$) but I don't see how to generalize my ideas. Does someone have a hint or insights on how to tackle this kind of problems? I'm really more interested in how someone could get to the answer, than the answer itself. Thanks for you advice :D

EDIT: @user299843 showed that we can get the result using a certain polynomial. Does someone know another proof?

Comment: My proof is basically just algebra, it only uses that a polynomial with more zeros than its degree is the zero polynomial. This fact holds for every field and hence hasn't anything to do with analysis.

Comment: @user299843 corrected

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Let $k\ge 0$, look at $f(t)=\text{Tr}((A+tB)^{k+1})$. What kind of function is this, what are its properties? If you need another hint, let me know!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got it! Your idea is to introduce some variability, may I ask what tipped you off about that?

Comment: @Michelle The problem already contains this variability; in fact, this answer *removes* a (spurious) degree of freedom, viz. $t:=\mu/\lambda$.

Comment: Indeed, the problem already contains this variability. I then calculate $\text{Tr}((A+B)^3)$ to get an expression containing $\text{Tr}(A^2B)$ (just to get a feeling for the problem) and then noticed that by replacing $B$ by $tB$ I got a polynomial, the rest you can fill in yourself.